Path rewrite in http proxy middleware not working
GET /users-api
Users Proxy - Original URL: /users-api
Users Proxy - Forwarding to: http://localhost/
it is not even hitting 4000
if i do like
target: 'http://localhost:4000/api/users',
directly set target this works fine
// Create proxy middleware for users API
const usersProxy = createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://localhost:4000',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/users-api': '/api/users'
    },
    on: {
        proxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
            proxyReq.setHeader('X-Proxy-Service', 'users');
            const targetUrl = `${proxyReq.protocol}//${proxyReq.host}${proxyReq.path}`;
            console.log('Users Proxy - Original URL:', req.originalUrl);
            console.log('Users Proxy - Forwarding to:', targetUrl);
        },
        proxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
            proxyRes.headers['x-proxied-by'] = 'users-proxy';
        },
        error: (err, req, res) => {
            console.error('Users Proxy Error:', err);
            res.status(500).json({ 
                error: 'Users Proxy Error', 
                message: err.message 
            });
        }
    }
});
// Apply proxy middlewares to specific routes
app.use('/users-api',usersProxy);

**GET /users-api Users Proxy - Original URL: /users-api Users Proxy - Forwarding to: http://localhost/ it is not even hitting 4000 if i do like target: 'http://localhost:4000/api/users', directly set target this works fine**

try custom rewriting
pathRewrite: function (path, req) { return path.replace('/users-api', '/api/users') }

